# Reason for IntegrityError on Field deletion?

Tags: python, django

I have a webservice setup with Django backend and I am trying to delete entries for my Field objects. Each Field is assigned to a User and there are a number of Assessments done in the Field. The Assessments are linked to the Fields via a foreign key. Upon deletion of the Field object I want to also delete all the Assessments for that `Field`, but keep the User.

I played around with the `on_deletion` parameter and if I set it to `CASCADE` the Django admin page shows me all the associated Assessment objects if I try to delete the Field object. However, I am still getting the following error:

> IntegrityError at /admin/dfto/field/ update or delete on table "field"
>   violates foreign key constraint "assessment_field_uuid_fkey" on table
>   "assessment" DETAIL:  Key
>   (uuid)=(f3a52c10-33be-42f9-995d-482025cea17b) is still referenced from
>   table "assessment".

These are my models for Reference:

```
class Assessment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_uuid = models.ForeignKey('Field', models.CASCADE, db_column='field_uuid',blank=True, null=True, related_name='assessments')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'assessment'

class Field(models.Model):
    uuid = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
    crop_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Crop, models.CASCADE, db_column='crop_uuid')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'field'
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error and/or provide a fix for me?

Comment: `CASCADE` this option affects **row** deletion. Not column.

Comment: Yes I know. I am not talking of "Fields" in the sense of columns. My model just happens to be called "Field" as well.

Comment: Have you applied migrations after changing to `CASCADE`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I did it just now. Did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: You are trying to delete from the django admin right? Is there something that my be preventing the admin from deleting the `Assesment` instances?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because field_uuid have argument 'models.CASCADE' so when you are deleting it, django also tries to delete any refences to this particular key, don't know how to fix it tho.

Comment: But that is exactly what I want. I want to delete all references deleted!